# Using MS-SQL With Maven2, Netbeans on a (Mac or Linux)

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, maven-2, maven

Looking for advice or a bit of help, to point me in the right direction.

I need to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server from a Java program, however, the drivers must be available in maven2 and work with NetBeans.

Any advice? (pointer to an example would be great) (Suicide is no longer an option)

Edit: I've found JTDS- is this a good solution?

Edit 2: Looks like it works... Here is how I have it configured...

Pom file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.steward.ccd</groupId>
    <artifactId>amalgainterface</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>amalgainterface</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ini4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>ini4j</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Java File

```
import java.sql.*;
import org.ini4j.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;

public class AmalgaInterface {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // MS-SQL Parameters
        String db_name = "xxxx";
        String db_hostname = "xxxx";
        String db_port = "1433";
        String db_userid = "xxxx";
        String db_password = "xxxx";
        String db_timeout = "10";

        // Check the Configuration file, and replace all service reference as required.
        // Get configuration
        String configFile = "/etc/test.conf";

        // Load data from INI files
        Ini ini = null;
        try {
            ini = new Ini(new File(configFile));
            db_name = ini.get("database", "name");
            db_hostname = ini.get("database", "host");
            db_userid = ini.get("database", "user");
            db_password = ini.get("database", "pass");
            db_port = ini.get("database", "port");
            db_timeout = ini.get("database", "dbtimeout");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Cannot load the configuration file");
        }

        // Create the connection string
        String db_connect_string = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + db_hostname + ":" + db_port + "/" + db_name + ";socketTimeout=" + db_timeout;

        // setup connection
        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(db_connect_string, db_userid, db_password);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }


        // clean up
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like it's time for you to set up your own repository :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [JTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/)

It's a type 4 jdbc driver and I believe it's available via [maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds/1.2.2).